# VB 6 and Right to Left layout windows application

Tags: vb6, right-to-left

I have an old windows application with it's Ocxs. I want to localize it's OCX to arabic. no problem on changing labels and strings.
but I can't change layout to Right to left.
I find some resources about using Mirroring in windows. but the provided samples don't help me. [Link1](http://www.cyberactivex.com/unicodetutorialvb.htm#RTL) & [Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688119#EDC) 
I'm not a VB fan and don't have enough experience.
Is there any clear and tested approach for VB to mirroring UI?

Comment: I believe those values can only be set at run time in an appropriate locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Platform SDK 2001

Complex Scripts in Edit Controls
A complex script is a language whose printed form is not laid out in a simple way. For example, a complex script may allow bi-directional rendering, contextual shaping of glyphs, or combining characters. The standard edit controls have been extended to support multilingual text and complex scripts. This includes not only input and display, but also correct cursor movement over character clusters (in Thai and Devanagari script, for example).

A well-written application will receive this support automatically, without modification. Again, you should consider adding support for right-to-left reading order and right alignment. In this case, toggle the extended style flags of the edit control window to control these attributes, as shown in the following example:

```
// ID_EDITCONTROL is the control ID in the resource file.
HANDLE hWndEdit = GetDlgItem(hDlg, ID_EDITCONTROL);
LONG lAlign = GetWindowLong(hWndEdit, GWL_EXSTYLE) ;

// To toggle alignment
lAlign ^= WS_EX_RIGHT ;

// To toggle reading order
lAlign ^= WS_EX_RTLREADING ;
```

After setting the lAlign value, enable the new display by setting the extended style of the edit control window as follows:

```
// This assumes your edit control is in a dialog box. If not, 
// get the edit control handle from another source.

SetWindowLong(hWndEdit, GWL_EXSTYLE, lAlign);
InvalidateRect(hWndEdit, NULL, FALSE);
```

Windows 2000/XP: The standard edit control supports a context menu that allows the user to toggle the reading order and insert/display Unicode bi-directional control characters.

Comment: Note that the OP is using VB6 and not all of these options may be available.

Comment: In the discussion it talks about DBCS which are pre unicode. I suspect the Arabic Language for NON Unicode Programs must be set up in Regional and Language Options..

Comment: Correct, VB6 is a mess for Unicode, while all strings are Unicode, most UI controls aren't (local codepage conversion), and any `Declare` API calls go through the same conversion.

Comment: I wrote a unicode text editor in VB6. This is what I hadto do. `Ret = LoadLibrary("c:\windows\system32\MSFTEDIT.dll")
 If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox "Load Lib " & Err.LastDllError
 Flags = WS_CHILD + WS_HSCROLL + WS_VSCROLL + WS_VISIBLE + ES_MULTILINE + ES_AUTOHSCROLL + ES_AUTOVSCROLL + ES_NOHIDESEL + ES_WANTRETURN
    Dim barray() As Byte
    barray = "RICHEDIT50W" & vbNullChar
    gRtfHwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_ACCEPTFILES + WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, barray(0), "", Flags, 0, 0, ScaleX(Me.ScaleWidth, vbTwips, vbPixels), ScaleY(Me.ScaleHeight, vbTwips, vbPixels), Me.hWnd, vbNull, App.hInstance, vbNull)
`

Comment: And to get a Text Object Object model (ie COM) to it `Dim TomObj as Object Ret = SendMessageAny(gRtfHwnd, EM_GETOLEINTERFACE, 0, TomObj) Set TomDoc = TomObj`